# Is there a sequence function for Try objects in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Scalaz has a sequence function that transforms a List[Option[A]] to a Option[List[A]]. Is there something similar for Try that transforms List[Try[A]] to Try[List[A]]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same `sequence` function if you have [the Try monad from scalaz-outlaws](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-outlaws/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/outlaws/std/Try.scala) in scope.

(As explained in the comments, this code violates the functor composition laws and so might lead to unexpected behaviour when used with some functions. It should be fine for your use case though)

Comment: could you explain why converting List[Try[A]] to Try[List[A]] break the laws? I can't find any comment in this thread.

Comment: It doesn't - that's what I meant by "your use case". But in other cases the Try monad violates the laws.